# Cakephp 3.x Ajax deleting data gives this Error: Unknown method "isNew"

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I try to delete a record with Ajax in CakePhp 3.0.6.

Here is the jquery in my View (start.ctp)

```
<script>
$('.delavailable').click(function(){
    var dataString = 'ID=' + $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ID/admins/delavailable.json',
        data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        }
    });
});
```

Controller (AdminsController.php)

```
    public function delavailable()
{

    $this->loadModel('TeamFree');

    if($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->TeamFree->delavailable($this->request->data['ID']);
    }
}
```

Model/Table (TeamFreeTable.php)

```
    public function delavailable($id){

         $query = $this->find('all')
        ->select(['TeamFree.ID'])
        ->where(['TeamFree.ID ='=>$id]);

        $this->delete($query);
}
```

This returns

```
{
"message": "Unknown method \u0022isNew\u0022",
"url": "\/ID\/admins\/delavailable.json",
"code": 500
```

}

Where do I fail?

Comment: What is your problem? Where fails your code?

Comment: It's not working and returns this error: Error: Unknown method “isNew”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a query object to [**`Table::delete()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_delete), that's not how it works, the method expects an entity, which you have to fetch in beforehand.

Simplified example

```
$this->delete($this->get($id));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Deleting Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html)**
- **[Cookbook > ... ORM > Retrieving Data ... > Getting a Single Entity by Primary Key](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-single-entity-by-primary-key)**
- **[Cookbook > ... ORM > Retrieving Data ... > Getting the First Result](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-the-first-result)**

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did put me on the right track. Feel free the optimize my working example below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Cookbook and some trial and error, this is how I managed to delete the row through Ajax.

```
    public function delavailable()
{

    $this->loadModel('TeamFree');

    $teamfree = $this->TeamFree->newEntity(); //create a temporary entity

    if($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $teamfree = $this->TeamFree->patchEntity($teamfree,$this->request->data); // put the request data into the temp entity
        $this->TeamFree->delete($this->TeamFree->get($teamfree->ID)); //use get() to place the entity property into the delete function and let the delete function refer to the entity
    }
}
```